# what's wrong with my mex-file?

Tags: c, matlab, mex

I'm trying to learn about matlab and mex files and wrote the following very simple code written in C to be called by matlab:

```
#include "mex.h"

void aplusb(int x, int y, int *z)
{
    z=x+y;
}

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    int *x;
    int *y;
    int *z;


    if(nrhs<2) 
    {
       mexErrMsgIdAndTxt( "MATLAB:aplusb:invalidNumInputs", "Need 2 values to sum");
    } 

    else if(nlhs>2) 
    {
        mexErrMsgIdAndTxt( "MATLAB:aplusb:invalidNumInputs", "Need one value to return.");
    }

    z = mxGetPr(plhs[0]);
    x = mxGetPr(prhs[0]);
    y = mxGetPr(prhs[1]);

  aplusb(x,y,z);
}
```

## Problem

I can compile correctly the code with mex aplusb.c. Just some warnings are returned:

```
aplusb.c:5:4: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast 
aplusb.c: in function ‘mexFunction’:
aplusb.c:25:5: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
aplusb.c:26:5: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
aplusb.c:27:5: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
```

but when i run the .m file which calls the .c file matlab crashes with segmentation violation.

What is wrong with my code if it compiled OK?

Comment: "assignment from incompatible pointer type" == not OK.

Comment: This question is **NOT** "too broad": it touches **several** basic concepts of mex programing. I strongly vote for re-opening it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### What's wrong

1. In `aplusb` you assign the sum of two ints to a pointer `z`, rather than `*z`.
2. You **cannot** access an output argument `mxGetPr(plhs[0])` without allocating it first.
3. `mxGetPr` returns pointers to **`double`** and not `int`. You cannot cast a pointer to `double` to a pointer to `int`: you can only cast `double`s to `int`s.

#### Fixing it

The function `mxGetPr` returns a **pointer** to the underlying `double` array represented by `mxArray`.

Therefore,

```
int * x = mxGetPr( prhs[0] );
```

is **WRONG**: `x` points to a 64bits in memroy that represent a **floating point** number,
but when you access it as `*x` you are telling the compiler to "read" these 64bits as 32bits **integer**.

One more thing: you have to **create** the output argument `plhs[0]`!

The correct way is

```
double * x = mxGetPr(prhs[0]);
double * y = mxGetPr(prhs[1]);
int z;
aplusb( *x /* cast double to int*/, *y /* cast double to int*/, &z ); // pass double and not poiners to double!
// allocate output
plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1, 1, mxREAL);
double *out = mxGetPr( plhs[0] );
out[0] = z; // cast int to double
```

#### What can you do?

In order to use this example for learning, you should **debug the mex file**.
How to do that? Just follow the instructions [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/debugging-c-c-language-mex-files.html).

See if you can spot all the troubles by yourself using the debuger - this is the best way to learn.

Comment: thanks for your help. But my problem still continues after your suggestion. Thanks again.

Comment: your suggestion compiled ok and matlab doesn't crash anymore (i don't have even warnings). But when I run my code, no matter what A and B values I give as input, the answer is always 6! it's weird, insn't it?

Comment: @mad - follow my suggestion on using a debuger. You'll learn a **LOT** this way.

Comment: I found the problem, the first argument was given two times. So I changed double * y = mxGetPr(prhs[0]); to double * y = mxGetPr(prhs[1]); thank you.

Answer (score 4):

There are several problems :

1. in `aplusb`, it should be `*z=x+y;`
2. do not pass pointers when calling the method : `aplusb(*x,*y,z);`
3. change the signature of `aplusb` to this : `void aplusb(double x, double y, double *z)` - after all you are passing pointer to double, and the compiler can not convert `double*` to `int*`
4. change `x`, `y` and `y` to be `double*` - not `int*`. mxGetPr returns `double*` and the compiler can not convert `double*` to `int*`

Comment: Thank you for helping me. But after your suggestion matlab still crashes :-(.

Comment: Thank you. I am quite newbie with mex-files on matlab. I will check out and return soon.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example implementation:

#### myadd.c

```
#include "mex.h"

void myadd(double x, double y, double *z)
{
    *z = x + y;
}

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    double x, y, z;

    /* Check for proper number of arguments. */
    if(nrhs!=2) {
        mexErrMsgIdAndTxt("mex:invalidNumInputs", "Two inputs required.");
    } else if(nlhs>1) {
        mexErrMsgIdAndTxt("mex:maxlhs", "Too many output arguments.");
    }

    /* Check for correct inputs. */
    if( !mxIsDouble(prhs[0]) || !mxIsDouble(prhs[1]) ||
            mxIsComplex(prhs[0]) || mxIsComplex(prhs[1]) ||
            mxGetNumberOfElements(prhs[0])!=1 ||
            mxGetNumberOfElements(prhs[1])!=1) {
        mexErrMsgIdAndTxt("mex:inputNotRealScalarDouble",
                "Inputs must be noncomplex scalar doubles.");
    }

    /* extract input */
    x = mxGetScalar(prhs[0]);
    y = mxGetScalar(prhs[1]);

    /* call subroutine */
    myadd(x, y, &z);

    /* assign output */
    plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleScalar(z);
}
```

#### MATLAB

```
>> mex myadd.c
>> myadd(10,20)
ans =
    30
```

Note that I added proper checks on the type of the input arguments (scalar non-complex doubles). This avoids crashing MATLAB if the input is otherwise.

Also I showed how to simplify the code by using "scalar" version of the MX functions, which bypasses the pointers.

Comment: Thank you, it also worked. Do you know a good tutorial about mex.h functions?

Comment: The documentation is a good start. Also there a number of examples shipped with MATLAB that you can study